# Different C++ program output between G++ 7.3.0 and G++ 9.3.0

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I'm a beginner C++ programmer. I'm attempting to find all of the scrabble words that can be made from a given set of letters, sort them by points value, and then by alphabetical, and then output them. Everything seemed to be going well on g++/gcc 9.3.0 until I compiled and ran the program with g++/gcc 7.3.0. On 7.3.0, it gives completely different output, but I need both of them to produce the same output. I've tried to find if any libraries/functions I've used are missing from 7.3.0, but haven't had any luck.

What's running differently/missing in this program between 7.3.0 and 9.3.0?

Thank you for your time!

Output on 9.3.0:

```
Please input a 7 letter sequence of scrabble tiles: aoetumt
a
at
et
to
ate
eat
eta
oat
out
tat
tau
tea
toe
tot
tut
am
auto
em
ma
mu
taut
teat
tote
tout
emu
mat
met
mot
tam
tom
atom
mate
matt
meat
moat
mote
moue
mute
mutt
tame
team
tome
matte
motet
totem
mutate
```

Output on 7.3.0:

```
Please input a 7 letter sequence of scrabble tiles: aoetumt
an
at
el
en
et
it
la
lo
no
on
or
so
ti
to
us
ad
ale
ant
are
ate
do
ear
eat
eon
era
eta
go
lea
let
lot
neo
net
not
nut
oar
oat
one
ora
ore
our
out
rat
roe
rot
rue
rut
sat
sea
set
sot
sue
tan
tar
tat
tau
tea
tee
ten
tie
tit
toe
ton
too
tot
tut
use
ado
aeon
aero
age
ago
aloe
alto
am
ante
aunt
auto
doe
dot
due
duo
east
eats
ego
em
gat
get
got
gut
iota
late
lout
lute
ma
mi
mu
neat
note
oats
ode
oust
outs
pa
rate
rote
roue
rout
sate
seat
stet
suet
tad
tag
tale
tare
taro
tart
tats
taut
teal
tear
teas
teat
ted
tent
test
toes
tog
tone
toot
tore
tort
tote
tots
tour
tout
trot
true
tug
tuna
tune
unto
up
urea
ace
act
ague
ah
aim
ape
apt
arm
atone
attle
autos
aw
bat
bet
boa
but
cat
cot
cue
cut
date
dote
duet
eh
elm
emu
gate
goat
gout
ha
ho
lam
man
mar
mat
men
met
moo
mot
oaten
oater
of
oh
opt
orate
otter
outer
pat
pea
pet
pot
put
ram
route
rum
saute
state
stout
sum
tab
tam
tap
tarot
taste
taunt
teats
tetra
toad
toast
toed
toga
tom
top
torte
total
totes
touts
treat
trout
tub
tutor
utter
we
ye
yo
abet
abut
aft
alum
amen
arum
astute
atom
atop
attune
ave
awe
aye
beat
beau
beta
boat
bout
butt
coat
cute
dam
eft
emit
emus
fat
foe
gam
gem
gmt
gum
gutta
hat
hoe
hot
hue
hut
item
lame
loam
mad
male
malt
mane
mare
mart
mast
mate
mats
matt
maul
meal
mean
meat
meet
melt
menu
mesa
mete
mite
mitt
moan
moat
mod
mole
molt
moot
more
most
mote
mots
moue
mud
mug
mule
muse
must
mute
mutt
name
notate
nutate
oaf
oft
ok
omen
omit
outlet
outsat
outset
ova
owe
pate
peat
poet
pout
putt
ream
roam
rotate
same
seam
smut
some
statue
stem
taco
tact
tame
tams
tape
tauten
taw
team
teem
term
the
time
tome
toms
toted
touter
tow
toy
tram
tuba
tube
two
vat
vet
wet
woe
yea
yet
you
about
acute
amour
amp
amuse
atoms
auk
autoed
bum
butte
cam
cotta
dame
demo
dome
duma
emote
fate
feat
game
guttae
hate
heat
made
map
mates
matte
matts
mead
meant
meats
metal
metro
moats
mob
mode
mom
mop
motel
motes
motet
motto
mount
mouse
mum
mutes
mutts
my
oak
oath
octet
outage
smote
steam
tamer
tames
taupe
teams
that
thou
tomes
totem
touted
tufa
tuft
tumor
uke
unmet
veto
vote
watt
acme
ammo
amount
amulet
beam
came
coma
come
datum
gamut
ham
hem
hum
mace
mated
matter
mattes
mature
maw
may
memo
mew
mho
mope
motets
mottle
mow
mutant
mutate
muted
mutest
mutter
mutton
ohm
omega
ovate
poem
puma
take
tamed
tamest
tamp
teak
teapot
theta
toke
tomato
tomb
totems
umbo
utmost
yam
yum
ahem
ax
cameo
comet
ex
fame
foam
fume
home
math
matted
meow
moated
moth
move
mulatto
mutates
ovum
ox
tempo
tempt
them
xu
amok
axe
jet
jot
jut
make
mauve
meaty
mouth
mutated
tax
tomcat
jute
mahout
oakum
outtake
text
jam
max
quo
exam
zeta
zoea
azote
quota
quote
toque
maze
matzo
```

The program:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

struct Scrabble
{
  string word;
  int points;
};

void swap(Scrabble *a, Scrabble *b)
{
  Scrabble temp = *a;
  *a = *b;
  *b = temp;
}

void bubbleSortPoints(vector<Scrabble> &vector)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++)
  {
    for(int j = 0; j < vector.size() - 1; j++)
    {
      int points1 = vector[j].points;
      int points2 = vector[j + 1].points;
      if (points1 > points2)
      {
        swap(&vector[j], &vector[j+1]);
      }
    }
  }
}

void bubbleSortWord(vector<Scrabble> &vector)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++)
  {
    for(int j = 0; j < vector.size() - 1; j++)
    {
      string word1 = vector[j].word;
      string word2 = vector[j + 1].word;
      if (word1.compare(word2))
      {
        swap(&vector[j], &vector[j+1]);
      }
    }
  }
}

int calcPoints(string word)
{
  int totalPoints = 0;
  vector<char> wordChar;
  vector<char> letters = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
  vector<int> points = {1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10};
  for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
  {
    wordChar.push_back(word.at(i));
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < wordChar.size(); i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < letters.size(); j++)
    {
      if (wordChar[i] == letters[j])
      {
        totalPoints += points[j];
      }
    }
  }

  return totalPoints;
}


//main method
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

  ifstream file("dict.txt");

  if (!file)
  {
    cerr << "An error occurred when opening the file: dict.txt" << endl;
    return 1;
  }

  string input;
  cout << "Please input a 7 letter sequence of scrabble tiles: ";
  cin >> input;
  if (input.size() != 7) {
    cout << "Please provide 7 characters of input.";
    return 2;
  }

  vector<Scrabble> validWords;
  string str = "";
  vector<char> temp;
  vector<char> found;
  bool flag = false;
  while (getline(file, str)) //loop while there are lines, O(n)
  {
    flag = false;
    temp.clear();
    found.clear();
    if (str.size() <= 7) //check if there are more than 7 characters
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
      {
        temp.push_back(input.at(i)); //make temp array of input
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) //iterate dictWord chars
      {
        if (flag == true) //if whole word has already been found to be valid
        {
          break;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < temp.size(); j++) //iterate input chars
        {
          if (str.at(i) == temp[j])
          {
            found.push_back(temp[j]);
            temp.erase(temp.begin() + (j));
            if (found.size() == str.length() - 1)
            {
              int points = calcPoints(str);
              Scrabble valid = {str, points}; //create struct
              validWords.push_back(valid); //push back to vector
              flag = true; //break both loops and move to next word
            }
            break;
          }
        }//j-loop
      }//i-loop
    }
  }//while-loop

  //sort by points
  bubbleSortPoints(validWords);

  //sort alphabetically
  bubbleSortWord(validWords);

  if (!file.eof())
  {
    cerr << "Error reading the file: dict.txt" << endl;
    return 3;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < validWords.size(); i++)
  {
    cout << validWords[i].word << "\n";
    //cout << validWords[i].word << "\n";
    //cout << validWords[i].points << "\n";
  }

  file.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `word1.compare(word2)` is true both when `word1 > word2` and when `word1 < word2`. It returns 0 when the two words are equal. So your `bubbleSortWord` doesn't really sort anything, it basically shuffles elements in some unpredictable order. Should be deterministic though.

Comment: `if (found.size() == str.length() - 1)` You are exiting too soon. You don't check the last character of `str` - you accept dictionary words whose prefix, ignoring the last character, can be constructed from given letters; the last character can be anything.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thanks! from checking the reference, I think simply the > operator from std::basic_string is what I should have went with for the bubble sort.

Comment: I did manage to find the solution to this, after pulling out more than enough hair! The problem was an off-by-one error, caused by a Windows-created text file used on one system having two end-line characters (\n\r) instead of the single one used in a UNIX text file (\n). After adjusting as Igor said, the program breaks with a Windows text-file but works as expected with a Unix created text file!